# Cannot access a file or folder in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xampp

I am new to Ubuntu. I am trying to install xampp in my ubuntu machine and have downloaded it to the "Downloads" folder with this name: "xampp-linux-x64-5.5.37-0-installer.run". One of the step is to change the xampp package to executable with this command:

```
sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-5.5.37-0-installer.run
```

or this way

```
sudo chmod +x /Downloads/xampp-linux-x64-5.5.37-0-installer.run
```

when I do that in the terminal i get this error:

```
chmod: cannot access ‘xampp-linux-x64-5.5.37-0-installer.run’: No such file or directory
```

What is happening and how do I correct this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem with Genymotion. None of the existing answers worked for me. Finally, I discovered this approach:

1. change file name
2. `sudo ./file name`

Don't use `.file` extension, `.pdf`, etc.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your current directory is, which you can find out by running `pwd` in the terminal.

The absolute path to the Downloads directory in Ubuntu is `~/Downloads`. If you want to run

```
chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-5.5.37-0-installer.run
```

you would have to be in the `~/Downloads` directory. Note that `sudo` is not required. However, if you are not in the `~/Downloads` directory, you would have to either provide the relative or absolute path to the `.run` file. If you want to provide the absolute path, then you would run

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/xampp-linux-x64-5.5.37-0-installer.run
```

Note the `~` in the command above, which is absent in the command you tried to run. Also note again that `sudo` is not required.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your installer is in your /Downloads directory. If it's not, then move it there and run `sudo chmod +x /Downloads/xampp-linux-x64-5.5.37-0-installer.run` again, and it should work.